# In my react library why is react and react-dom installed even I use peerDependencies for them

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node-modules

I learn React and JavaScript.

After running npm install I see that `react` and `react-dom` is in my node_modules, why is that?

I have a small problem when using the [library component](https://github.com/iamhosseindhv/notistack) that I get duplicate react error.
So I try to learn how to fix this

here is the package.json

```
{
    "name": "notistack",
    "version": "1.0.10",
    "description": "Highly customizable notification snackbars (toasts) that can be stacked on top of each other",
    "main": "src/index.js",
    "module": "dist/notistack.esm.js",
    "types": "src/index.d.ts",
    "license": "MIT",
    "author": {
        "name": "Hossein Dehnokhalaji",
        "email": "hossein.dehnavi98@yahoo.com",
        "url": "https://github.com/iamhosseindhv/notistack"
    },
    "homepage": "https://www.iamhosseindhv.com/notistack",
    "repository": {
        "url": "git+https://github.com/iamhosseindhv/notistack.git",
        "type": "git"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "build": "tsdx build --transpileOnly --entry ./src/index.js",
        "prebuild": "npm run docs",
        "prepublishOnly": "npm run build",
        "docs": "rimraf typedoc.json && typedoc --tsconfig",
        "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx"
    },
    "peerDependencies": {
        "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
        "react": "^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.8.3",
        "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.5",
        "@types/node": "^13.9.0",
        "@types/react": "^16.9.23",
        "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.5",
        "@types/react-is": "^16.7.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^3.9.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^3.9.1",
        "babel-plugin-optimize-clsx": "^2.6.1",
        "eslint": "^7.7.0",
        "eslint-config-airbnb": "~18.2.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "~2.22.0",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.3.1",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.20.6",
        "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
        "rollup-plugin-bundle-size": "^1.0.3",
        "rollup-plugin-copy": "^3.3.0",
        "tsdx": "^0.13.2",
        "typedoc": "^0.16.11",
        "typescript": "^3.8.3"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "clsx": "^1.1.0",
        "hoist-non-react-statics": "^3.3.0"
    },
    "bugs": {
        "url": "https://github.com/iamhosseindhv/notistack/issues"
    },
    "funding": {
        "type": "opencollective",
        "url": "https://opencollective.com/notistack"
    },
    "contributors": [
        "Hossein Dehnokhalaji (https://www.iamhosseindhv.com/)"
    ],
    "keywords": [
        "notistack",
        "enqueueSnackbar",
        "snackbarprovider",
        "useSnackbar",
        "multiple",
        "react",
        "javascript",
        "material-ui",
        "toast",
        "redux",
        "snackbar",
        "stacked",
        "notification",
        "material design",
        "hossein",
        "dehnokhalaji",
        "iamhosseindhv"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is your npm version 1, 2 or 7? If yes, then it's expected behavior

Comment: @BorisTB I have npm -v 7.21.1. The problem is when I use the library in my react app I get this [error](https://snipboard.io/zIU68j.jpg). After some tests I see I do have loaded two React versions. what you think how to fix that

Comment: Library looks ok. I'm not sure how far you are with learning, but if you know difference between class and functional component, make sure you are not using any hooks in class component. For example you can't call useState() inside render() method

Comment: @BorisTB Thanks yes your right, yes I read about that. When I use this library then it's working like so. `import { useSnackbar } from 'notistack';`` but when I fork the lib and do "npm link" then I get that error